# Running a script with parameters with node-windows nodeJs package

Tags: node.js, windows-services, node-windows

The script i want to run as a service requires 'start' as parameter.

How do i setup the parameter with `node-windows`?

Here the setup js script from the [project](https://github.com/coreybutler/node-windows) page:

```
var Service = require('node-windows').Service;

// Create a new service object
var svc = new Service({
  name:'Hello World',
  description: 'The nodejs.org example web server.',
  script: 'C:\\path\\to\\wiki.js',
  nodeOptions: [
    '--harmony',
    '--max_old_space_size=4096'
  ]
});

// Listen for the "install" event, which indicates the
// process is available as a service.
svc.on('install',function(){
  svc.start();
});

svc.install();
```

Setting script value as 'wiki start' result in error because the module treats it as a file. 
Here the log:

```
Starting C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe  --harmony --max_old_space_size=4096 C:\Users\<me>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-windows\lib\wrapper.js --file ..\wiki.js --log "wiki.js wrapper" --grow 0.25 --wait 1 --maxrestarts 3 --abortonerror n --stopparentfirst undefined "-- start"
```

I also try to send in `nodeOptions`, adding '-- start' to array but the module add it to the command line as string, i.e. "-- start".

Answer (score 0):

This is what the [scriptOptions](https://github.com/coreybutler/node-windows#command-line-options) parameter is for. It was introduced with [node-windows@0.1.11](https://github.com/coreybutler/node-windows/releases/tag/0.1.11)

```js
var svc = new Service({
  name:'Hello World',
  description: 'The nodejs.org example web server.',
  script: 'C:\\path\\to\\wiki.js',
  scriptOptions: 'start'
});
```